# iPhone development: Extract SSL certificate information

Tags: iphone, ssl-certificate

I'm developing an app where I want to setup a secure channel between my app and a server.
I want to extract information like CA and algorithm from the SSL certificate on the server. How do I achieve that? Can it be done with NSUrlConnection, CFNetwork or do I have to develop a whole lot myself with BSD sockets? Is there some open source library I can use perhaps? Code examples are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to check that information. If the certificate isn't valid [connection:didFailWithError:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection:didFailWithError:) is called, but beyond that, you can't really interact with the SSL certificate in any way.

You will likely have to roll your own or find libraries to help you out to do this.